# Clear idle persisted workflows in a MS SQL instance store

Tags: workflow, appfabric, workflowservice

I wonder how to safely delete idle workflows from persisted storage.
What I have in my mind is to run simple SQL like this one:

```
delete from [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[InstancesTable]
where ExecutionStatus = 'Idle'
```

Is this method "safe"? Or some related data has to be deleted as well?
Any alternatives?

This is needed because if newer version of workflows is deployed, some parts do not work well, for example [DelayActivities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.delayactivity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do not trigger and do not resume unloaded workflows.
Clearing "old" idle workflows - the only workarround I know.